# How can I access the data stored in silver layer by azure databricks in oracle database?

Tags: oracle, azure-databricks

The data in the silver layer of data bricks that is stored in ADLS gen2 needs to be accessed in the Oracle app (consider it as an Oracle database) and we should be able to query the tables using SQL. It is not directly possible to get data from Databricks to the Oracle database, I tried DBeaver but did not get the results.

Comment: Your oracle data files are stored in the ADLS and you want to create tables on top of the files that are stored in the ADLS and query them using SQL/synapse(formerly SQL data warehouse) correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: @DileeprajnarayanThumula  Databricks stores the data in ADLS as parquet files(data is tables stored in parquet files) and I want to access these files in my Oracle database. And I should be able to query that data using SQL in the Oracle database.